# Detect if file should be downloaded from UIWebview

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, ios, objective-c

My goal is to detect audio files (mp3, mp4, m4a, and wav) from clicking a link in a UIWebview.  I have the delegate call

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

implemented and it checks if the url extension ends in one of the mentioned extensions.  The problem is when I try to download files from sites like mail.google.com and mail.yahoo.com and others that don't use direct links.

Is there a generic way to get a files type from clicking any link or do you have to do it on a per site basis.  I'm a noob when it comes to html/javascript coding.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Dmarpco Like Rapidshare, Mediafire, Two mentioned by you and many others site does not provide Direct Links. They give URLs which are safe and can be used only by Downloader. They convert URL when downloader send request. You may also convert URLs If you can.

Comment: Exactly.  I just found this so maybe it is the same concept. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176936/examine-a-response-while-webviewshouldstartloadwithrequestnaviagionttype-w?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I didn't see this link first, but it has everything required to solve this problem.

[?examine a response while webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:naviagiontType... waits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176936/examine-a-response-while-webviewshouldstartloadwithrequestnaviagionttype-w?rq=1)