# UIWebView mp3 download from javascript player

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview, download

I need to download `.mp3` files from `UIWebView`, it's easy to [when you have a link clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176936/examine-a-response-while-webviewshouldstartloadwithrequestnaviagionttype-w?rq=1), but if `mp3` starts to play by javascript? For example [here](https://vk.com/audio) (registration needed) we have something like this

```
<div class="play_btn fl_l">
  <div class="play_btn_wrap"><div class="play_new" id="play7325930_231345788"></div></div>
  <input type="hidden" id="audio_info7325930_231345788" value="https://cs9-6v4.vk.me/p3/3dc60c16c95561.mp3?extra=H-mELXpfiAvYwJVjUANivI-emKPdMaP8gdpaxEOnRJqNHqX9RzIZIQXV0-DfpDnUvaDV-KtyuZwtgnomV4rwAY8vN_DZngc,199" />
</div>`
```

I could detect `MPAVController` begin to play, but nothing else. Is it possible to use js observer `onclick` and after it detect link?